# How to get system time in formatted style swift?

Tags: swift, nsdate, decoding

I have such time which I have to send to the server:

```
2019-03-06T14:49:55+01:00
```

I thought that I can do it in such way:

```
NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970))
```

but I got such time:

```
2021-01-24 15:42:31 +0000
```

I thought that I have to user decoding pattern, so used such way:

```
let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss+z"

let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "MMM dd,yyyy"
        
let time = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970))

if let date = dateFormatterGet.date(from: time.description) {
   print(dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date))
} else {
   print("There was an error decoding the string")
}
```

but its output was:

```
There was an error decoding the string
```

what means that I can't decode this time in such way. What I did wrong?

Comment: `let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter(); formatter.timeZone = .current; let string = formatter.string(from: Date())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a string from a date from a time interval from a date, three of the conversions are waste.

The conversion failed because `time.description` doesn't match the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss+z`

To get an ISO8601 string with time zone the date format is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` and you have to specify a fixed locale

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
let isoString = formatter.string(from: Date())
```

There is a shorter way as suggested by Rob in the comments

```
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
formatter.timeZone = .current
let isoString = formatter.string(from: Date())
```